# Optimize getting all sub-strings of a binary string

Tags: javascript, string, binary, substring, bit

The code is to convert a decimal number to binary, generate all possible sub-strings of the binary string and calculate the odd number of 0's and 1's in each of the sub-string and finally return the total count. Running this code gives timeout error in sites like hackerrank. What approach should be used to reduce the complexity here? I tried pushing all the binary numbers in an array & then iterating it separately to avoid 0(n^3). But even that doesn't seem to work. Should a dynamic programming approach be taken here?

```js
    function getAllSubstrings(str) {
  let result = [];
  let n = str.length
  let oddZeroCnt = 0;
  let oddOneCnt = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (let j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
      let substr = str.substring(i, j);
      let zeroSubStr = (substr.split("0").length - 1)
      let oneSubStr = (substr.split("1").length - 1)
      if (zeroSubStr % 2 === 1) {
        oddZeroCnt++
      }
      if (oneSubStr % 2 === 1) {
        oddOneCnt++
      }
    }
  return oddZeroCnt + " " + oddOneCnt;
}

function getOddCounts(decNum) {
  return getAllSubstrings((decNum >> BigInt(0)).toString(2))
}
let input = BigInt(17)
console.log(getOddCounts(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) You don't need strings. You can check wether a bit is set at the position of a number with `number & (1 << position)`.

(2) You don't need to count even *and* odds. Every non odd number is even, therefore `total = even + odd`. If you know the total number of combinations and the number of odd values, you can easily calculate the number of even.

(3) You only have to iterate twice (O(n²)). If you have a look at these combinations of 17 bitwise, starting at 0:

```
  1     ≠> odd
  10    => odd
  100   => odd
  1000  => odd
  10001 ≠> even
```

then you can see that the combinations are even until a 1 occurs, then they are odd until another 1 occurs. If you keep track wether the previous combination was even or odd, you can easily determine wether the next combination is odd just by looking at the current bit:

```
  let odd = false, odds = 0;

  /*...*/
     if(number & (1 << position)) odd = !odd;
     if(odd)  odds += 1;
```